# Ninjatrader drawing dots based on a condition

Tags: c#

I am new to coding in NinjaTrader. I am trying to draw a dot beneath bars based on a condition being true.

if I make my condition as simple as possible, like this:

```
if (Close[0] < Open[0])
```

-- I can get the dots to display correctly.

But, if I try to refer to previous bars, like this:

```
if (Close[0] < Open[1])
```

-- the code does not work. So, I assume it is the condition itself which I am getting wrong.

Can anybody explain why this change would stop the code working, and how I would correctly refer to previous bars?

Any help appreciated.

Here's the rest of the code.

```
protected override void OnBarUpdate()
    {

        {   

            //if (Close[0] < Open[0]) 
            if (Close[1] > Open[1])
            //if(Close[1] < Close[0] && Close[1] < Close[2])

                { 
                    myBarCloses=1;
                } else {
                    myBarCloses=0;
                }

                if (myBarCloses==1) 
                {
                    DrawDot(CurrentBar.ToString() +"BarCloseDot",true, 0, Low[0]*0.997, Color.Magenta);
                }

        }      

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anybody else has a need for this information, it requires a check for enough bars in the data series you are accessing.

I don't know whether posting external links is permitted, so I'll assume it is not. A Google search should find the info.

I had to amend the code as below.

```
protected override void OnBarUpdate()
{
    if (CurrentBar < 1)
        return;

    if (Close[0] < Open[1])
        // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For these cases, you can just create the code using the Strategy Builder. I did that and this is what I got:

```
    if (BarsInProgress != 0) 
        return;

    if (CurrentBars[0] < 1)
        return;

     // Set 1
    if (Close[1] > Open[1])
    {
        Draw.Dot(this, @"Temp01 Dot_1", false, 0, 3, Brushes.CornflowerBlue);
    }
```

The advantage of this method is that you always get a code that works.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, with which I agree, I like to include this in the top of my method as well:

```
protected override void OnBarUpdate()
{
    CandleState candleState = CandleState.HistoricalClosed;
    if (Bars.Count - 1 == CurrentBar)
    {
        if (State != State.Historical)
        {
            if (IsFirstTickOfBar)
                candleState = CandleState.RealtimeNew;
            else
                candleState = CandleState.RealtimeUpdate;
        }
        else
            candleState = CandleState.HistoricalCurrent;
    }

    switch (candleState)
    {
        case CandleState.RealtimeNew:
            // Do something for this case
            break;
            
        // [Other cases here...]

    }
    
    // [ Other code ... ]
}
```

And then, somewhere else in your class:

```
private enum CandleState
{
    HistoricalClosed,
    HistoricalCurrent,
    RealtimeNew,
    RealtimeUpdate
}
```

This gives an easy way to determine the state of the data for various data handling scenarios.